# Data file format for 3d plots in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I have file(s) containing N X values and M Y values.  Also one containing Z at each value of (X,Y).  So N rows and M columns.
I did this:

```
a=load('z.txt')
surf(a)
```

which plots Z ok but the axes are just the datapoint number.  How do I get the axes to match the X and Y data?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
x=load('x.txt')
y=load('y.txt')
z=load('z.txt')
surf(x,y,z)
```

Although there are probably more elegant ways.